# Fullcalendar JSON/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

Currently I am working on Fullcalendar v3.

> https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/
>
> https://fullcalendar.io/docs

My `events` code to set the events required to display items in the calendar:

```
eventSources: [{

            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url     : 'dispatcher.php',
                    type    : 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data    : {
                        //  requires UNIX timestamps
                        start     : start.unix(),
                        end       : end.unix(),
                        component : 'Rak',
                        controller: 'Read',
                        task      : 'getCalendarEvents'
                    },
                    success : function(doc) {
                        var events = [];
                        $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                            events.push({
                                title    : $(this).attr('title'),
                                start    : $(this).attr('start'), // will be parsed
                                end      : $(this).attr('end'), // will be parsed
                                className: $(this).attr('className')
                            });
                        });
                        callback(events);
                        console.log(doc);
                    }

                });
            }
        }]
```

**Console.log(doc)**:

> 0: {id: "1", title: "Testtesttest", start: "2019-01-15", end:
>   "2019-01-16", className: "event-azure"} length: 1

However... item is NOT displayed in the calendar. **What am I doing wrong?** Currently I am clueless.

A JSON format is being sent and should have been used in the events.

Thanks a lot for any help!

**Hardcoded example which works to show the required format:**

```
events: [
    {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2010-01-05',
      end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
      allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
  ]
```

Comment: if (according to your question text) `Console.log(doc):` already produces a valid event array then why are you creating a separate `events` variable? And if `doc` is indeed a JSON array then it won't have any attributes. Are you getting confused by the example from the fullCalendar docs which shows how to process an XML response (not a JSON response)? You pass `events` to fullcalendar, so what does `console.log(events);` output?

Comment: You may find that simply writing `success : function(doc) { callback(doc); }` works without needing any further processing.

Comment: Hi @ADyson , thank you for your contribution! Yes, as your sharply noted I am confused by the example provided by fullCalendar. `console.log(events);` gives an empty array.

Comment: Ok so have you tried simply `success : function(doc) { callback(doc); }` as I suggested? I strongly suspect that may be all you need to do.

Comment: @ADyson, it just working.  `callback(doc);` did it for me. Thank you so much! Please provide the solution (and if possible with explanation and documentation) as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question text `console.log(doc)` already produces a valid event array (with valid values and field names as per the [fullCalendar documentation of an event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object)), so you should not need to create a separate `events` variable, or indeed process `doc` in any way at all.

Instead you can simply pass the data directly to fullCalendar without doing anything to it:

```
success : function(doc) { 
  callback(doc); 
}
```

Comment: This should be added to the documentation of fullcalendar. I am going to get in contact with them.

Comment: @RonnieOosting you know in your situation you could actually use the simpler https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed method instead to fetch your events. No need for the custom function really. The custom function is intended for situations such as the one in the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function documentation where the server does not already produce output in the necessary format. I would expect that's why it gives a more convoluted example, but then also notes "However, if you have the choice, JSON is a better idea because you can just specify a feed URL.".

Comment: Yes, that is possible but I do dislike it that way as how I use my code. I prefer to use my controllers and models with the functions and redirecting as I have set it up, haha! This way I can make it ready for other components as well, only thing i have to request is an array the controller can return (exit). All other code is ready to reuse now.

Comment: @RonnieOosting Not sure I understand your point... I'm pretty sure that changing the way you set the event feed in fullCalendar to the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed method would not require you to change anything in your server-side controllers. You might just have to override the start/end params to use the UNIX output (unless of course your server would already accept the yyyy-mm-dd format that fullCalendar automatically provides)

Comment: Sorry, English is my second language. Perhaps I do not explain it clearly. For example `url: '/myfeed.php`: in my code i do not want to get data from a single file (myfeed.php), i want to have it requested by a method. So I request data by requesting a function in PHP. Do the checks/make it a smooth array/validate it and return the 'event' results. Perhaps there are other methods, if that is the case which provide the same results as I want it; my javascript knowledge it limited.

Comment: @RonnieOosting in the code you posted in the question, you already hard-coded "'dispatcher.php'" into the $.ajax options as being the PHP endpoint. I don't see any code by which you are changing that in your JavaScript. So I don't see any difference between that and hard-coded it into the "url" option in "events" instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186708/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-adyson).

Comment: @mickmackusa can you post a proper question about it please? Then I will be able to take a look, and also have space to write a proper answer if I can. Thanks.

Comment: @mickmackusa the only thing that jumps out at me from a very brief scan of the code is that there's no method in fullCalendar on the calendar object called `refetch()`. Does that not generate a console error? I would guess you're thinking of `calendar.refetchEvents();` - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents. `refetch` only exist on eventSource objects, not the main calendar. I can't be sure that's really your only problem though. Anyway this is wildly off-topic on some other person's thread, which is why it should have its own question. The code from your link is enough

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: {
               url: "<?php echo Yii::getAlias('@COMPANY_URL') . '/shedule/get_event' ?>",
          }
});
```

In the dispatcher.php you have to generate json like below format

```
   [
    {
      title: 'Event Title1',
      start: '2015-03-17T13:13:55.008',
      end: '2015-03-19T13:13:55.008'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event Title2',
      start: '2015-03-17T13:13:55-0400',
      end: '2015-03-19T13:13:55-0400'
    }
  ]
```

In my controller did like this :

```
public function actionGet_event() {

        $events = Shedule::find()->all();
        $eventsJson = array();
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $url = "https://www.google.co.in/";
            $eventsJson[] = array(
                'description' => $event->event_desc,
                'title' => $event->event_title,
                'start' => $event->event_date,
                'edit' => $url,
                'className' => ["event", "bg-color-greenLight"],
                'icon' => 'fa-check',
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($eventsJson);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for your quick answer. dispatcher is a local file who handles where to go. I go to my controller, get the data from the model and `exit(json_encode($result));`. This should do the same, or am I wrong?  `$result` contains the events data.

Comment: This looks promising! Thank you. Will try it out and will report to you within an hour or two

Comment: @RonnieOosting Ok

Comment: Hi Rahul, this is what I received: `[{"title":"Testtesttest","start":"2019-1-1","className":"event-azure"}]`. But It does not show the item. Within the  I build the array as you gave me, return this array to the controller.  Controller receives this array and does: `echo json_encode($result);` or `exit(json_encode($result));`. When I do echo, it does not pass success in ajax, exit does. But still I do not see the events in the calendar. Do you have any idea what might go wrong? If you prefer I can start a chat instead of comment to each other in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186706/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-rahul-pawar).